# Overlaying SVG image with color, gradient or another image

Tags: svg, overlay

Is is possible to apply a color/gradient/pattern overlay to an SVG `image` the same way as Adobe Photoshop implements “Layer styles”?

- If a pixel of the `image` is transparent, the resulting pixel is transparent.
- If a pixel of the `image` is semi-transparent, alpha value of the resulting pixel is equal to or less than alpha value of that pixel.
- A pixel of a mask, defined by a color, a gradient or another image, is drawn on top of the corresponding pixel of the `image`, based on alpha channel of the mask.

In other words, something like the `fill` attribute applying to an `image` element instead of a shape (unfortunately, it has no effect).

Of course, the images, colors and gradients are dynamically set.

The only trick I've found so far is using a large internal shadow, but I'd like to animate the overlay position also.

Comment: Maybe you are talking about svg filters? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter, https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html

Comment: @Nikolay It seems `feBlend` does what I need, but still not sure, will read further. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, there is also feColorMatrix that can do basically any operation at all.

Comment: @Nikolay If you convert the comments into an answer, I'll mark it as accepted. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, filters do what I need.

For instance, this is Photoshop-like “color overlay” with green color and opacity 95%:

```
<defs>
<filter id="myfilter">
        <feFlood result="floodFill" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" flood-color="green" flood-opacity="0.95"/>
        <feBlend result="mergedImg" in="SourceGraphic" in2="floodFill" mode="multiply" />
        <feComposite in2="SourceGraphic" in="mergedImg" operator="in" />
</filter>
</defs>
```

To apply, set the following style:

```
<image xlink:href="img/my.png" x="100" y="100" width="256" height="256" style="filter:url(#myfilter);" />
```